# Is there a built-in in Python 3 that checks whether a character is a "basic" algebraic symbol?

Tags: string, python-3.x, methods, numbers, built-in

I know the string methods *str.isdigit*, *str.isdecimal* and *str.isnumeric*.

I'm looking for a built-in method that checks if a character is algebraic, meaning that it can be found in a declaration of a decimal number.

The above mentioned methods return **False** for *'-1'* and *'1.0'*.

I can use *isdigit* to retrieve a positive integer from a string:

```
string = 'number=123'
number = ''.join([d for d in string if d.isdigit()])  # returns '123'
```

But that doesn't work for negative integers or floats.

Imagine a method called *isnumber* that works like this:

```
def isnumber(s):
    for c in s:
        if c not in list('.+-0123456789'):
            return False
    return True

string1 = 'number=-1'
string2 = 'number=0.1'
number1 = ''.join([d for d in string1 if d.isnumber()])  # returns '-1'
number2 = ''.join([d for d in string2 if d.isnumber()])  # returns '0.1'
```

The idea is to test against a set of "basic" algebraic characters. The string does not have to contain a valid Python number. It could also be an IP address like **255.255.0.1**.
.
Does a handy built-in that works approximately like that exist?

If not, why not? It would be much more efficient than a python function and very useful. I've seen alot of examples on *stackoverflow* that use *str.isdigit()* to retrieve a positive integer from a string. Is there a reason why there isn't a built-in like that, although there are three different methods that do almost the same thing?

Comment: No, there is no such function. Why not? Because there is no one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score -1):

No such function exists. There are a bunch of odd characters that can be part of number literals in Python, such as `o`, `x` and `b` in the prefix of integers of non-decimal bases, and `e` to introduce the exponential part of a float. I think those plus the hex digits (`0-9` and `A-F`) and sign characters and the decimal point are all you need.

You can put together a string with the right character yourself and test against it:

```
from string import hex_digits

num_literal_chars = hex_digits + "oxOX.+-"
```

That will get a bunch of garbage though if you use it to test against mixed text and numbers:

```
string1 = "foo. bar. 0xDEADBEEF 10.0.0.1"
print("".join(c for c in string1 if c in num_literal_chars))
# prints "foo.ba.0xDEADBEEF10.0.0.1"
```

The fact that it gives you a bunch of junk is probably why no builtin function exists to do this. If you want to match a certain kind of number out of a string, write an appropriate regular expression to match that specific kind of number. Don't try to do it character-by-character, or try to match all the different kinds of Python numbers.

Comment: All right, I've edited my answer. Basically, matching all possible "number characters" is going to give you junk a lot of the time. Unlike digits that don't often appear in non-numeric contexts, other bits like periods and dashes do occur all the time in other kinds of text.

Comment: In the example I gave in my question, with only adding the characters '.+-' to a set of digits to support decimals, you will not get junk if you know what you're doing. Also, this is not even relevant, because we're talking about a category of characters. And testing against a set of "classic" algebraic characters like '+-*/.0123456789' could be an absolutely legit string method. Whether it returns junk or not is up to the implementation.